# Excel operation resume when NA

Tags: excel

I have a data frame on excel and I need to make an operation on excel for a friend. So can't use python or R.

[image]

I want to create a new column where I perform this operation:

ABS(A2-B2)+ABS(A2-C2)+ABS(A2-D2)+ABS(A2-E2)+ABS(A2-F2)+ABS(A2-G2)+ABS(A2-H2)+ABS(A2-I2)

The problem is that some rows have NA, therefore excel result is an error. Ideally I want this:
Row BB

ABS(A2-B2)+ABS(A2-C2)+ABS(A2-D2)+ABS(A2-E2)+ABS(A2-F2) excluding +ABS(A2-G2)+ABS(A2-H2)+ABS(A2-I2) because these last three rows got NA values.

ABS(6-7)+ABS(6-7)+ABS(6-12)+ABS(6-20)+ABS(6-2) = 26

If anyone can help that will be very appreciated !
Thanks

Comment: *"I want to be able to tell excel to stop the operation"* - if Excel cannot evaluate the formula, it effectively *stops* the calculation for the particular cell (and displays some error #value). What do you get currently as a result, and what precisely do you want to get differently? Please clarify.

Comment: So test for NA and deal with it either ISNA() or IFERROR()...

Comment: I have edited the questions to answer to your comments.

Comment: The solutions I gave you in my first comment will still work. Encase each row calculation in an iferror().

Answer (score 0):

So try:

=Iferror(ABS(A2-B2),0)+iferror(ABS(A2-C2),0)+iferror(ABS(A2-D2),0)+iferror(ABS(A2-E2),0)+iferror(ABS(A2-F2),0)+iferror(ABS(A2-G2),0)+iferror(ABS(A2-H2),0)+iferror(ABS(A2-I2),0)

Comment: It doesn't work because the result is 0. I don't want the result to be 0. I have also tried to erase the NA. But then it assumes there is a 0 in those rows and it makes my results also incorrect. Thanks for answering though.

Comment: So replace those 0 with 1 or a 1000... But if all of them have errors what value do you expect. Perhaps you should provide a **clear** example of the actual results to be used, then we might be able to get somewhere.

Comment: I can't replace them with 0 neither a 1000. I did say what I want in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If your NAs are always at the end of the row, you could use this

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ABS(A1-B1:INDEX(B1:I1,COUNT(B1:I1))))
```

`COUNT` only counts numbers so it will only include cells up to where the numbers stop. `INDEX(B2:I2,COUNT(B2:I2))` will return a reference to F2 in your example. Evaluating the `B2:INDEX` part looks like this

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ABS(A2-{7,7,12,20,2}))
```

then

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ABS({-1,-1,-6,-14,4}))
=SUMPRODUCT({1,1,6,14,4})
```

`SUMPRODUCT` evaluates like an array formula, so you can avoid typing each `ABS` individually.